# Carleson's lectures at UCLA

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, soft-question

It seems that Professor Lennart Carleson gave a series of Lectures at UCLA in 1985. For example, one could find several mentions about these lectures in the book by Garnett & Marshal (see for example, notes at the end of chapters II and III). I would like to know whether is aware of theses lectures; preferably available in electronic form?

I'm not sure about the context of these lectures; But, it seems that it was about some topics in complex analysis; potential theory; (quasi-)conformal mappings, harmonic measures and so on.

*Garnett, John B.; Marshall, Donald E.*, Harmonic measure, New Mathematical Monographs 2. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-0-521-72060-1/pbk). xv, 571 p. (2008). [ZBL1139.31001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1139.31001).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have contacted the mathematics department at UCLA, and then received the following information from Professor Garnett (emphasis mine):

> For nine or ten winter quarters beginning 1985 Lennart Carleson gave a lecture course at UCLA.   The topics included Potential Theory,  Harmonic Measure,  Complex Dynamics, Iteration Theory,  Conformal Mappings and some others I can't recall. **There are no lecture notes published or recorded in the UCLA Mathematics Reading Room.** However, the Complex Dynamics became the very nice book Complex Dynamics by Carleson and Gamelin,  and parts of the lectures on conformal mappings and harmonic measure are in my book Harmonic Measure written with Donald Marshall.
>
> The most elementary course was second term graduate real analysis using the book by Wheeden and Zymund.

> **[The 1985] course was about harmonic measure. Almost everything from it is in Garnett-Marshall Chapters I - IV and then VI, VIII and IX.**